# How can I store image to iCloud from my iphone application?

Tags: iphone, icloud, photo-gallery

I got a project like **MyPhoto Pro** app in iPhone [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myphoto-pro-smart-photo-manager/id374269181?mt=8) ([website](http://myphototips.tumblr.com/)).

Please, can any one help or guide me what are the technologies and frameworks i should use for developing?

But my primary things is that image should stored in iCloud.

Comment: can you put some code of how you achiece it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **iCloud** file storage see [Designing for Documents in iCloud](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForDocumentsIniCloud.html) in docs.

Then check `NSFileManager` class, section *Managing ICloud-Based Items*.

- `-ubiquityIdentityToken` – **detect** iCloud availability
- `-URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:` – **obtain URL** for iCloud directory (container)
- `-setUbiquitous:itemAtURL:destinationURL:error:` – **move** any local file to iCloud (or vice versa); one URL must be local and one must point into one of the iCloud containers
- `-startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:error:` – **download** the file content
- `-evictUbiquitousItemAtURL:error:` – **delete** iCloud file.

Also check `NSMetadataQuery` and `NSMetadataItem` classes used to **discover** new iCloud files. iCloud will automatically give you **only metadata** of the file, but content must be downloaded explicitely (see the methods above)

Comment: thanks for iCloud storage reference. please give or sugest some refference for photo album and gallery creation

Comment: There are many ways of implementing photo gallery. You need to specify what exact problems do you have or what would you want to achieve. Displaying list, grid, stripes? Storing photos in directories, database, plists?

Comment: my problem is I want to create a folder and stored in that folder like wise i want to create own customized folder for each time when i clicked Add New Folder button and also i want to know which one easy for retrieving images from Directories or database?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right place for questions about what technologies to use. You can store photos in directories (folders). Name of the photo can be some timestamp and then you can have photo metadata in property list named with the same timestamp. Those plist files would also be synced over iCloud.